# Firestore rules allow specific document but not collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to allow a user to read a specific document /customers/cumstomerkey  but not to get the whole collection. How can I achieve that?  Following rule allows access to get the whole collection:

```
  match /customers/{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if true;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to read about [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) in security rules.  If you have a single document that should be gettable, just call out the path and allow `get` access on just that:

```
match /customers/cumstomerkey {
  allow get;
}
```